# Google maps 3.54 adding style to the map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, maps

I'm currently working on a vue2 project with google maps 3.54 (latest version), this is required to use this version because of advancedMarkers.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${this.mapKey}&callback=isMapLoad&libraries=marker&v=3.54
```

I read all the documentation about styling a map, and i have done it before on other version. But i do not find the way ir.

I try to set a style on the init:

```js
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  mapId: 'GMAP_ID',
  language: this.$i18n.locale,
  center: this.defaultCoords,
  zoom: this.zoom,
  styles: [
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
     {
       color: '#f40000',
     },
     {
       visibility: 'on',
     },
    ],
  }
 ]
})
```

Or after the init with:

```js
const styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
 [
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [
     {
       color: '#f40000',
     },
     {
       visibility: 'on',
     },
    ],
  }
 ]
)
this.map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType)
this.map.setMapTypeId('styled_map')

// i have added to my script url the libraries maps to have StyledMapType
```

I got no error, but nothing change in both cases. What can i try?

---

**UPDATE**

There is a **working example** of the trouble:
https://jsfiddle.net/981w4zxb/1/

If you remove the `mapId` like in the example, the style is apply, but in that case the markers doesn't work anymore.

If you add the `mapid`, the advanced markers is display, but the `styles` not apply.

I want both, it's mandatory too used **advanced markers** and **styles** without the cloud but legacy `styles`.

Comment: I think it should be `MapTypeStyle` and not `StyleMapType`. Please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapTypeStyle

Comment: Thanks, but it appear to not exist on the map object.
But i found something if i remove the ```mapId``` i can see that the map style change with setOption({styles})!
So, how can i change the mapStyle using a mapId?

Comment: @RaphaelRlt unfortunately, you can't. You'll have to reinitialize the map. More info here in [my handbook on Google Maps](https://gmapsbook.com/learn-google-maps/styles-themes-bee54879cccd4b4fb0e2c3fa918e5515).

Comment: @Yrll: not quite. You'd pass `MapTypeStyle` to the `StyleMapType` constructor - so the OP did it right: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#StyledMapType.constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about how it is with Vue but your code looks correct – with or without `&v=3.54`.

The thing is, if you instantiate your map with a `mapId`, the `styles` attribute in the constructor **will not** override the map's appearance.

So, if you don't have cloud styling associated with your `mapId`, remove it from the constructor. Your `styles` should apply right away. And I suspect `this.map.setMapTypeId(...)` will take effect too.

**UPDATE**

You cannot use `mapId`s and `styles` at the same time. When you do, you'll get the warning:

> A Map's styles property cannot be set when a `mapId` is present. When a `mapId` is present, Map styles are controlled via the cloud console. Please see documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#cloud_tooling

Given that your style definitions are stored in a DB, you'll likely need to create individual `mapId`s and their associated cloud style…

Alternatively, you can reconsider your usage of Advanced Markers. Here's [a guide to explore alternatives](https://spatialized.io/advanced-google-maps-markers-definitive-guide-94c5a070615e436ab0a255b9f5100a88). *Dislaimer: I wrote the guide.*

Finally, you might want to keep an eye on the `gcloud cli` which might, at some future point, let you programmatically create `mapId`s and styles -- just like Google did for [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys/create).

Comment: Thanks, it's what i have understand too. But if i removed the mapId, the maps display a error, because i use the advanced markers, and this can only be used with a map initialized with mapId =/

And i can't used cloud plateform because the mapStyle come from different data source on a database.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible Vue example (eg on stackblitz)? Without the API key of course.

Comment: Yes, thanks i update the response to explain https://jsfiddle.net/981w4zxb/1/

Comment: Thanks. Please check my updated answer. BTW, your fiddle contains your API key -- not a good practice (:

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's not my key api but the key from google doc example ;)